# Collapsible content not showing, probably due to scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added an `animated collapsible`, just as on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp). But something somehow goes wrong, since clicking on the button does not reveal the collapsible content. I think it may have something to do with the script(s), though the `navbar` keeps on being sticky and responsive(which is good). Could anyone help me out?

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "navbar";
    }
  }

window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction2()
};

var navbar = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0];
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction2() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fcf3e3;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ad {
  background-color: #fbf4e9;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

ul.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #f9eedd;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

ul.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: #8e8275;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 7px;
}

ul.navbar li.links {
  float: left;
}

ul.navbar li.rechts {
  float: right;
}

ul.navbar li.icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  ul.navbar li:not(:first-child),
  space,
  .ad {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.navbar li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.navbar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.navbar.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.navbar.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.navbar li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px
  }
}

space {
  margin-left: 15px
}

.collapsible {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: .3vmin;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 17vmin;
  height: 2.6vmin;
  font-size: 1.6vmin;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.collapsible.active,
.collapsible:hover,
a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.1px #c4b29c;
  transition: max-height 0.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  padding: 12px 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 17vmin;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
  margin: 0 auto 1.3vmin auto
}

.content a {
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<div class="ad">Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</div>
<div>
  <ul class="navbar" id="myTopnav">
    <li class="links"><a href="index.html">Loren ipsum</a></li>
    <li class="links">
      <space></space>
    </li>
    <li class="links"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="links"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="rechts"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class=icon><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
  efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>

<button type=button class=collapsible>Contact▾</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>This is the content</p>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you used `display: none` on `.content` check below:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.1px #c4b29c;
  transition: max-height 0.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
}


.collapsible {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: .3vmin;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button type=button class=collapsible>Contact▾</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>This is the content</p>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```